# java groupBy and summarize on multiple field

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm trying to use the Java summarize which I have just discovered and they are just perfect for my use case.

The only issue is that I can't make it working when I need to summarize on multiple field:

```
final Map<PackageType, LongSummaryStatistics> map2 = artifactory.getStorageInfo()
            .getRepositorySummaries()
            .stream()
            .map(o -> RepositorySummaryValue.from(o))
            .collect(groupingBy(
                k -> k.getPackageType(),
                summarizingLong(k -> k.filesCount)
                ));
```

this is my `RepositorySummaryValue` class:

```
@lombok.Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    private static class RepositorySummaryValue {

        long filesCount;

        @NonNull
        PackageType packageType;

        @NonNull
        String key;

        @NonNull
        RepositoryType type;

        long usedSpaceBytes;

        @SneakyThrows
        static RepositorySummaryValue from(RepositorySummary source) {
            return builder()
                .filesCount(source.getFilesCount())
                .packageType(source.getPackageType())
                .key(source.getKey())
                .type(source.getType())
                .usedSpaceBytes(source.getUsedSpaceBytes())
                .build();
        }
    }
```

What I want is to get summarise also for `summarizingLong(k -> k.usedSpaceBytes)`

Any way for doing it?

=========EDIT============
I'm using Java 8

Comment: When you’re using JDK 12 or newer, you can use [the `teeing` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction))

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that with a little setup would allow any number of fields of some type `T` to be summarized.  It may give you some ideas.  It makes use of the `compute*` features of a map introduced in `Java 8`.

I used a record in lieu of a class to hold the data.

- first, set up a list of method references to get the values you want.
- then, initialize another list with the titles of names of those values (here I used your names but the data is just for demo).  *`Note:` There are many ways to do this.  A single list with a `record` holding the name and method reference would be another way.*
- create a map of maps to house the results.  The key to the outer map is the `packageType`, the key to the inner map is the name of the field you are summarizing for each packageType.

Now simply iterate over the list of data, and build the map.  The details of how the `compute*` methods work are explained in the [Map Interface JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) but here is a quick summary.

`computeIfAbsent` will evaluate its second argument if the supplied key is not there.  That second argument (here it's the inner map) is returned for access.  In this case, another `computeIfAbsent` is used to see if that map has a key for the field.  If not it adds it and creates a `LongSummaryStatistic` instance wit the key for the field name.  That instance is also made available for access.  The data item is then `accepted` and the statistics updated.

```
public class Summarizing {

    record Data(String getPackageType, long getFilesCount,
        long getUsedSpaceBytes) {
    }

    static List<Function<Data, Long>> summaryFields = List
        .of(Data::getFilesCount, Data::getUsedSpaceBytes);
   
    static List<String> names = List.of("filesCount", "usedSpaceBytes");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Data> list = List.of(new Data("foo", 10, 100),
        new Data("bar", 20, 200),
        new Data("foo", 30, 300),
        new Data("bar", 40, 400));

    Map<String, Map<String, LongSummaryStatistics>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Data d : list) {
        Map<String, LongSummaryStatistics> innerMap = result
            .computeIfAbsent(d.getPackageType(),
                v -> new HashMap<>());
        for (int i = 0; i < summaryFields.size(); i++) {
           innerMap.computeIfAbsent(names.get(i),
              v -> new LongSummaryStatistics())
            .accept(summaryFields.get(i)
                .apply(d));
        }
    }

    result.entrySet().forEach(e-> {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
        for (Entry<?,?> ee : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("  "  + ee);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

prints

```
bar
  filesCount=LongSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=60, min=20, average=30.000000, max=40}
  usedSpaceBytes=LongSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=600, min=200, average=300.000000, max=400}
foo
  filesCount=LongSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=40, min=10, average=20.000000, max=30}
  usedSpaceBytes=LongSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=400, min=100, average=200.000000, max=300}
```